# Math with Tkinter IntVar()'s not working?

Tags: python, tkinter

Essentially, I'm using Tkinter in python so that 1 is added to a variable when a button is pushed. I have another variable that is equal to my first variable times 10. When I hit the button that adds one to my original variable, the second variable (x*10) is not doubled. Take a look:

```
def add1():
    var1.set(var1.get() + 1)

def pringvar3()
    print(var3.get())

from tkinter import *
main = Tk()
button = Button(main, text="Add 1", command=add1)
button.pack()
button2 = Button(main, text="Print var3", command=printvar3)
button2.pack()

var1 = IntVar()
var1.set(1)
var2 = IntVar()
var2.set(10)
var3 = IntVar()
var3.set(var2.get() * var1.get())
```

What's wrong with that code? When I click the buttons, first 1 then 2, it still prints the variable as 10.

Comment: `Tkinter` IntVars work exactly like normal Python variables.  The value of `var3` is set as a concrete number when the line `var3.set(var2.get() * var1.get())` gets executed.  After it's set, the value of `var3` isn't dependent on future values of `var1` or `var2`

Comment: @zehnpaard see, I don't do that much work with constantly changing variables (despite their name, **variables**...), so I actually didn't know that.  I'm a very amateur programmer, as you can see.  I also thought it'd update itself because when you do `label = Label(main, textvariable=var1)` it automatically updates the label when `var1` changes.  Thanks, though!

Comment: No problem, and makes sense you thought that from how Label and Tkinter IntVars interact.  The interaction between those things are specially coded to make them interdependent, and it's more of an exception rather than a rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bunch of spelling errors and missing colons, but more importantly you don't change the value in the function callback. Remember, you only set the value once, you never actually reset it.

```
def printvar3():
    global var3
    var3.set(var2.get() * var1.get())
    print(var3.get())
```

Comment: This is a bug waiting to happen, you have a function called `printvar3` that actually modifies the value of a global variable.

Comment: It's not my issue. Drew decided to work his program that way.

Comment: And there is no bug waiting to happen. I hate how people discourage globals, eval, exec, and traditional file opening. This is a matter of preference.

Comment: Okay, okay.  First of all, I'm trying to modify a global variable.  That is my goal.  Second of all, I know there are spelling mistakes and missing colons and stuff, my actual programs is well over a thousand lines of code and I was dumbing down this bit as much as possible, and I typed it up in around ninety seconds.  Thirdly, this is a great answer, and it's exactly what I'm looking for, so remove the downvotes please.

Comment: I don't downvote on use of `globals` etc.  I think this snippet is pretty dangerous, because it's actually modifying instead of printing var3.

Comment: @zehnpaard It's supposed to modify var3.  And it's not instead of, it's in addition to.

Comment: @Malik Brahimi I think you're a little harsh too... I don't think he's trying to hate.  At first glance it does seem kind of dangerous if it's not what I'm intending to do.  He's just trying to be helpful.

Comment: Thanks Drew, there really is no hate involved.  I downvoted because I (still) feel that this is a dangerous path to go down. Everytime you use `var3`, you need to do the same value update beforehand, which rapidly becomes hard to remember, especially if you're not immediately printing the output to check.  If you want var3 to always be var1*var2, then you're better off not having var3 at all, and just directly code `var1.get() * var2.get()` where you previously wanted var3.

Answer (score 0):

`tkinter` `IntVar` objects don't update others that may have used their value at some point, so changing `var1` won't automatically update `var3` -- you have to make it happen explicitly.

Here's a simple demonstration based on your code that has an extra button added that does this when clicked:

```
def add1():
    var1.set(var1.get() + 1)

def updatevar3():
    var3.set(var2.get() * var1.get())  # recalulate value

def printvar3():
    print(var3.get())

from tkinter import *

main = Tk()
button = Button(main, text="Add 1", command=add1)
button.pack()
button2 = Button(main, text="Update var3", command=updatevar3)
button2.pack()
button3 = Button(main, text="Print var3", command=printvar3)
button3.pack()

var1 = IntVar()
var1.set(1)
var2 = IntVar()
var2.set(10)
var3 = IntVar()
var3.set(var2.get() * var1.get())  # set initial value

main.mainloop()
print('done')
```